# Please fix or close this history question

Tags: discussion, adopt-a-question

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/are-the-claims-about-others-beside-bush-claimed-that-iraq-had-wmds-valid

I personally think it's too broad and vague. It was the result of an extended discussion - as such the question itself is super long and is in desperate need of TLC.

Please do one of these two things:

- Fix the question through an Epic Edit, then answer it
- Vote to close

Use the answers to discuss what to do, but *don't forget to act*.